# View Password At login

Tags: 19.04, login-screen, gdm

I have some users who cant seem to remember their passwords, so I am  looking for some ways to better help the users. There are web apps and mobile apps that allow the user to click on the "eye" icon to view their password as they're typing it in.

My question is; can this option be added to the default GNOME login screen?

Comment: Isn't gnome the default for 10.04?

Comment: Could you support making login passwordless? http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/enable-passwordless-login-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Oops ,sorry I meant Gnome Desktop, and no I do not want togo Passwordless

Answer (score 0):

1) Settings has a “Show Password” checkbox

2) [Seahorse](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/seahorse/blob/2730c9761503238c5fb890bd8f163bbcf5cbf4ec/gkr/gkr-password-entry.vala#L34-36) uses a end-aligned inline icon with the tooltip “Show/Hide password”

Comment: I will try this tonight.

Comment: I did not see the "Shadow Password" checkbox in my Settings. And I haven't figured out how to implement the suggested Seahorse tool-tip. Any help with the tool-tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with more details. Where *exactly* is the “Show Password” checkbox? As OP mentioned there doesn't seem to be any in Settings. Perhaps add a screenshot.